# Flutter FlatButton and Icon introducing unwanted padding

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to control the size of the FlatButton with an Icon in it. But it seems the Icon is breaking the button.

```
return Container(width: 180,height:30,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        FlatButton(onPressed: () =>  _selectedDateDailyChart > 0 ? _adjustDate(-1) : null,
          child: Container(
            color:Colors.red,
            width: 20,
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero
        ),
        Container(child: Text(currentDate, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3.apply(fontSizeDelta: -2)),),
        FlatButton(onPressed: () =>  _selectedDateDailyChart > 0 ? _adjustDate(-1) : null,
          child: Container(
            width: 20,
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero
        ),
      ],),
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Here is what it looks like]

Comment: It's the icon itself. It has got the padding. You can see it here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/arrow_back_ios-constant.html

Also, you can change the icon to `arrow_back_ios_outlined` or create an svg yourself and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want put an `InkWell` widget around you `Icon` insted, same result, 0 padding.

Comment: Hey there, I tried this solution but it is not working.

Comment: You still have the padding ?

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use Expanded Widget like this "to make a balance between the two button wrap the other Button with expanded too"

```
child: Container(
              width: 180,
              height: 30,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () => _selectedDateDailyChart > 0
                            ? _adjustDate(-1)
                            : null,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          width: 20,
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(currentDate,
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .headline3
                            .apply(fontSizeDelta: -2)),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () =>
                          _selectedDateDailyChart > 0 ? _adjustDate(-1) : null,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 20,
                        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```